# How to use winapi functions in ring0 (kernel mode)?

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver

I can't call `FileTimeToSystemTime()` method in driver. The error is:

***error C4013: 'FileTimeToSystemTime' undefined; assuming extern returning int***.

Also I can not include `windows.h` because I already included `ntddk.h`, and it will cause a lot of errors. 
If I declare it as `BOOL FileTimeToSystemTime(IN const PFILETIME, OUT PSYSTEMTIME);` in the header I get next errors:

***error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'FileTimeToSystemTime'***

***error C2059: syntax error : ';'***

***error C2059: syntax error : 'type'***

***error C4013: 'FileTimeToSystemTime' undefined; assuming extern returning int***

And finally, If I write an implementation for this method:

```
BOOL FileTimeToSystemTime(const PFILETIME pFileTime, PSYSTEMTIME pSystemTime)
{
    CALL_ENTRY
    long long tmp;
    memcpy(&tmp, pFileTime, sizeof (FILETIME));
    time_t aTime_t = tmp / 10000;
    tm aTm;

    if (!gmtime_r(&aTime_t, &aTm ))
        return FALSE;

    pSystemTime->wYear = aTm.tm_year + 1900;
    pSystemTime->wMonth = aTm.tm_mon;
    pSystemTime->wDayOfWeek = aTm.tm_wday;
    pSystemTime->wDay = aTm.tm_mday;
    pSystemTime->wHour = aTm.tm_hour;
    pSystemTime->wMinute = aTm.tm_min;
    pSystemTime->wSecond = aTm.tm_sec;
    pSystemTime->wMilliseconds = 0;

    return TRUE;
}
```

I got the same errors as listed above. What is the right way to call this method in kernel mode ? Or how to call winapi functions from windows driver in general ?

Comment: -1. You want write driver, but you dont have elemental knowledge. Please read some documentation first. Or you wish write BSOD generator????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The winapi is a *sub-system* on top of the native operating system.  There were original three sub-systems for Windows NT: Posix, OS/2 and Win32.  Designed to make porting programs from other operating system easy.  Win32 was heavily influenced by the api for Windows 3.x.  Posix and OS/2 were largely ignored and have been removed, Win32 won by a land-slide.  These days called "Winapi" to avoid the "32", it was ported to 64-bit code with very modest changes.

In device driver land, you no longer work with such a sub-system, you program the native operating system.  So you'll need to forget the winapi functions and use the native API instead.

You obtain the system time with [KeQuerySystemTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553068%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Convert to local time if necessary ExSystemTimeToLocalTime().  You can generate the equivalent of SYSTEMTIME with the [RtlTimeToTimeFields()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) helper function.